# Is there a way to display the length of the sides of a jsxgraph polygon?

Tags: geometry, polygon, jsxgraph

I'm trying to draw a polygon from a list of points with labels on each of the sides (borders) with the length of the sides?

Is there a simple way to get this happening?

Here's a snippet with what I've got at present. Note that I want to be able to use an arbitrary number of points, not just three if at all possible.

```
const board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox', {
  boundingbox: [-5, 5, 5, -5],
  axis: true
});
var points = [
  [0, 0],
  [0, 1],
  [1, 0]
];

var pg = board.create('polygon', points, {
  fixed: true,
  hasInnerPoints: true,
  vertices: {
    visible: false
  },
  borders: {
    names: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    withLabel: true
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set the label text of each border to be a function. This has to be done after the construction of the polygon. A possible solution would look like this:

```
const board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox', { 
    boundingbox: [-5, 5, 5, -5], axis:true
});

var points = [
  [0, 0],
  [0, 2],
  [2, 0]
];

var pg = board.create('polygon', points, {
  fixed: true,
  hasInnerPoints: true,
  vertices: {
    visible: false
  },
  borders: {
    names: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    label: { offset: [-10, 10] },
    withLabel: true
  }
});

// Overwrite the labels of the borders:
for (let i = 0; i < pg.borders.length; i++) {
    pg.borders[i].label.setText( () => pg.borders[i].L().toFixed(2) );
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/h6knmgjc/ for a working example.